# Scala: how to format a string that is read from conf file

Tags: python, scala

I know I can replace the variables in a string using string interpolation.
However, If the string is read from a conf file, How can I replace them then? 
Basically, I am translating some python code to scala. In python, I can do string format like this.

```
srpquerylink.format(server=srpserver[si], key = keyword, pn = i + 1, ipp=itemperpage, start= itemperpage * i)
```

What is the scala's solution for string format?

Answer (score 3):

In scala you can do

```
"%s %s, age %d".format(firstName, lastName, age)
```

as well as

```
String.format("%s %s, age %d", firstName, lastName, age)
```

Does this answer your question?